# how to know the time interval between two click (python and qtdesigner)

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to know how to calculate the time interval between the click of two buttons? I'm using qt designer and python. 
My two buttons names are ("start" and "blue")

```
ui.start.clicked.connect(mytime.start)
ui.blue.clicked.connect(mytime.elapsed)
```

But I don't know how to get the time interval? 
Thank you.

Comment: [QElapsedTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about pyqt, but I think you could do use the function `time` from the module `time`. You can bind `start = time.time()` to your start button and `end = time.time()` to your end button. Then, for each interval use `i = end - start`. Hope this helped.